# How to handle virtual aliases when only the %u is stored in LDAP

Tags: ldap, postfix-mta

Here's the relevant part of the config:

```
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
#virtual_mailbox_domains = new.example.com example.com www.example.com mail.example.com imap.example.com virtual.example.com 
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/usr/pkg/et/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf 
virtual_transport = maildrop
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/usr/pkg/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf
virtual_alias_domains = new.example.com example.com www.example.com mail.example.com imap.example.com virtual.example.com

ldap-aliases.cf
server_host = a.b.c.d
search_base = dc=example, dc=com
query_filter = mailalias=%u
result_attribute = mail
```

I have a somewhat strange setup and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to do what I want. I'm using virutal hosting with (almost) all lookups taking place via ldap. The exception is that the domains the server accepts mail for are listed in the config file (see above).

The strange part is that in LDAP only the `%u` part is stored in the user record, in a custom field, mailalias. So for exmaple, I have:

mailalias: postmaster
mailalias: security
...etc

for me, as I'm the admin.

The ldap-aliases.cf works as a virtual alias, but it maps postmaster@anything.tld (which is obviously not what I want). I thought the alias domains would limit the aliases to only the example.com tlds listed.

Is there a way to keep the `%u` part in ldap and limit virtual_alias_maps to only match if the domain is one of the *.example.com ones listed?

Thanks in advance,

Jason M.

Answer (score 0):

I almost had it. I tried domain_name = example.com new.example.com, etc. in ldap-mailbox.cf but that didn't do it. But domain = example.com new.example.com, etc. in the ldap_aliases works. The lines that changed are:

```
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/usr/pkg/etc/postfix/ldap-mailbox.cf<br>
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/usr/pkg/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf<br>
```

ldap-aliases.cf

```
server_host = a.b.c.d
search_base = dc=example, dc=com
domain = example.com new.example.com www.example.com virtual.example.com
query_filter = mailalias=%u
result_attribute = mail
```

ldap-mailbox.cf is the same as the original ldap-aliases.cf:

```
ldap-mailbox.cf
server_host = a.b.c.d
search_base = dc=example, dc=com
query_filter = mailalias=%u
result_attribute = mail
```

I wonder if I could use the ldap-aliases for the virtual_mailbox_maps? Or if I could use a hash:/ inside the ldap-aliases.cf?